# Which verse/scripture is this shloka from? (tavam vastu nushmshi gamdyi yatr gavo bhuri sringa ayasa)

Tags: scripture, mantras, rig-veda, reference-request, shloka

I am trying to identify the source of the sloka. I came across this sloka while listening to a lecture:

> tavam vastu nushmshi gamdyi gavo bhuri sringa ayasa

तावां वस्तु नुष्म्षि गम्द्यि यत्र गावो भूरि शृङ्ग अयासा

In the lecture, it was mentioned it's from *Rigveda* but I tried searching online and couldn't find, can anyone suggest how to find the original verse, maybe my transliteration from audio to text isn't correct, hence I can't find it online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed this shloka is from `Rig Veda 1.154.6`

> ता वां॒ वास्तू॑न्युश्मसि॒ गम॑ध्यै॒ यत्र॒ गावो॒ भूरि॑शृङ्गा अ॒यास॑:। अत्राह॒ तदु॑रुगा॒यस्य॒ वृष्ण॑: पर॒मं प॒दमव॑ भाति॒ भूरि॑ ॥

meaning

> We pary (to Viṣṇu) that you may both go to those regions where the many-pointed and wide-spreading rays (of light expand); for here the supreme station of the many-hymned, the showerer (of benefits), shines (with) great (splendour)

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc830651.html